# How to tell if JRE or JDK is installed

Tags: java, macos, java-8

I have one computer that I intentionally installed JDK on. I have another computer with JRE, for, among other things, testing. However, when I got a java application working on this computer, and then tried it on another, it complained that JDK was required. How can I check if JDK was somehow installed on my system? Note: the computer in question is a Mac.

Comment: Can you post the full text of the error, including how you're trying to run it? You don't need the JDK to run a Java program, just the JRE.

Comment: It was a friends computer- something about installing command line tools. I'll comment again when I get a chance to inspect it again.

Comment: It sounds like you might be talking about making sure that Java is on your path, but that's just a guess. Either way, you only need the JRE to run Java programs. You need the JDK to compile them.

Comment: Only few java programs need a JDK, IDEs, servlet containers like tomcat to compile JSPs and some others. What kind of application has the problem?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You can open up terminal and simply type

```
java -version // this will check your JRE version
javac -version // this will check your java compiler version (JDK) if you installed
```

this should show you the version of java installed on the system (assuming that you have set the path of the java in system environment).

And if you haven't, add it via

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/jdk1.x
```

and if you unsure if you have java at all on your system just use `find` in terminal

i.e.   `find / -name "java"`

(edit: `command -v java` will look up java on your PATH, will be much faster than `find` when java is installed and correctly placed on PATH).

Comment: @MaciejCygan, Why is my JAVA_HOME pointing to a JRE instead of a JDK?

Comment: @Pacerier Why ?? i do not know that for sure lol!. Maybe you do not  have JDK installed ? Running windows or linux ??

Comment: @MaciejCygan, I'm using windows. Yea, I've got a JDK installed too.

Comment: @Pacerier You can edit / or make a entry if none found - inside your environmental variables.

Comment: @MaciejCygan, Yea, but why is my JAVA_HOME pointing to a JRE instead of a JDK?

Comment: @Pacerier probably because you have installed JDK before JRE ? could really be anything. The bottom line is to get the right path after you have installed both.

Comment: Does this answer related to windows? if yes, "java -version" is returing with an error saying it is not a recognized command.

Comment: @ahsant if it says so then your environmental variable is not set correctly. Otherwise it would print java info :)

Comment: btw, find is not necessary in this case. which BINARY_TO__EXECUTE will find your binary file; so, in this case which java will work

Comment: How do I tell from this output if my installation is JRE or JDK?

Answer (score 22):

Normally a jdk installation has javac in the environment path variables ... so if you check for javac in the path, that's pretty much a good indicator that you have a jdk installed.

Comment: I realize that the OP was asking about a Mac, so it may be different there. But as for Windows, this test does not seem reliable. I just checked, and I do NOT have `javac` in my path, but I DO have a jdk installed. (In my case, my JAVA_HOME is pointed to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45`)

Comment: Yeah, you are right cause javac is actually located in %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 10):

@maciej-cygan described the process well, however in order to find your java path:

`$ which java`

it gives you the path of `java` binary file which is a linked file in `/usr/bin` directory. next:

`$ cd /usr/bin/ && ls -la | grep java`

find the pointed location which is something as follows (for me):

[image]
then `cd` to the pointed directory to find the real home directory for Java. next:

`$ ls -la | grep java`

which is as follows in this case:

[image]

so as it's obvious in the screenshot, my Java home directory is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`. So accordingly I need to add JAVA_HOME to my bash profile (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc. depending on your OS) like below:

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"`

Here you go!

Answer (score 1):

A generic, pure Java solution..

For Windows and MacOS, the following can be inferred (most of the time)...

```
public static boolean isJDK() {
    String path = System.getProperty("sun.boot.library.path");
    if(path != null && path.contains("jdk")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However... on Linux this isn't as reliable... For example...

- Many JREs on Linux contain `openjdk` the path
- There's no guarantee that the JRE doesn't also contain a JDK.

So a more fail-safe approach is to check for the existence of the `javac` executable.

```
public static boolean isJDK() {
    String path = System.getProperty("sun.boot.library.path");
    if(path != null) {
        String javacPath = "";
        if(path.endsWith(File.separator + "bin")) {
            javacPath = path;
        } else {
            int libIndex = path.lastIndexOf(File.separator + "lib");
            if(libIndex > 0) {
                javacPath = path.substring(0, libIndex) + File.separator + "bin";
            }
        }
        if(!javacPath.isEmpty()) {
            return new File(javacPath, "javac").exists() || new File(javacPath, "javac.exe").exists();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Warning:** This will still fail for JRE + JDK combos which report the JRE's `sun.boot.library.path` identically between the JRE and the JDK.  For example, Fedora's JDK will fail (or pass depending on how you look at it) when the above code is run.  See unit tests below for more info...

Unit tests:

```sh
# Unix
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1|grep "sun.boot.library.path"
# Windows
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1|find "sun.boot.library.path"
```

```sh
    # PASS: MacOS AdoptOpenJDK JDK11
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib

    # PASS: Windows Oracle JDK12
    c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin

    # PASS: Windows Oracle JRE8
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin

    # PASS: Windows Oracle JDK8
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin

    # PASS: Ubuntu AdoptOpenJDK JDK11
    /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/lib

    # PASS: Ubuntu Oracle JDK11
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/lib

    # PASS: Fedora OpenJDK JDK8
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-1.b16.fc24.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64

    #### FAIL: Fedora OpenJDK JDK8
    /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_231-amd64/jre/lib/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

according to JAVA documentation, the JDK should be installed in this path:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkmajor.minor.macro[_update].jdk
```

See the uninstall JDK part at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

So if you can find such folder then the JDK is installed

Answer (score 0):

> the computer in question is a Mac.

A macOS-only solution:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8+ --exec javac -version
```

Where `1.8+` is Java 1.8 or higher.

Unfortunately, the `java_home` helper does not set the proper return code, so checking for failure requires parsing the output (e.g. `2>&1 |grep -v "Unable"`) which varies based on locale.

Note, Java may also exist in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin`, but at time of writing this, I'm unaware of a JRE that installs there which contains `javac` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for Windows users, using JDK.

Be careful that `javac` might not be consistent with `JAVA_HOME`

For example, I had:

```
javac -version
javac 21.0.1
```

But when I checked the location of `$JAVA_HOME$`

```
echo $JAVA_HOME$
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19$
```

This is apparently because Java uses a junction/symlink to install javac into the `PATH` environment variable:

```
where javac
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javac.exe
```

As shown in my environment variables here:
[image]

More on [symlinks in Windows here](https://superuser.com/q/524669/292784)

And a solution, [which is to put `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` into the `PATH`, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68983320/1175496)

All of this happened to me because I was trying to [use `gradle` / `gradlew clean build` with an incompatible version of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857351/1175496)