# SpringBoot Project Giving no Output just a white Label Error Page what could be the possible cause

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am Starting to Learn Spring Boot But i cannot Get past the Beginner Guide to just display the Model Attributes

My Model Controller

```
package com.rahulweb.spring.springtest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller

    public class ModelController {

          @RequestMapping("/test")
            public String demo(Model model) {
                Person person = new Person();
                person.setName("Rahul");
                person.setAge("22");
                model.addAttribute("person", person);
                return "index";
            }


    }
```

and My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

FirstName :<span th:text="${person.name}"></span>
Age : <span th:text="${person.age}"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

My Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.rahulweb.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>springtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TestModel</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

[image: Project Structure]

There is no error in console when i hit localhost:8080/test just I get Whitelabel error page with 404 as the status

When running maven clean and install getting the following error in console

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestModel 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ springtest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ springtest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\SINGH\Documents\Spring\TestModel\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.297 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-01T10:33:39+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/180M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project springtest: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My Spring boot Starter Class

```
package com.rahulweb.spring.springtest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestModelApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestModelApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the whitelabel error page states? 404 or 500?

Comment: it says a 404 .

Comment: Since you have the actuator, hit `http://localhost:8080/mappings` to see how is `ModelController` mapped. Hard to tell what the error is. Can you share the sample somewhere? That would be so much easier than guessing.

Comment: That actuator i had just added a while back, whilr going through the problem and searching the solution on the web but still no luck after adding the actuator

Comment: Shall i post it on git ? Or tell me any place i can

Comment: https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/TestBoot

Git link to the project,Please help me its very important thanks in adv

Comment: no errors in your logs? if you can upload the project into some git repository would be usefull

Comment: The project works fine for me, try `mvn spring-boot:run` in your shell and try again.

Comment: In your shell i didn't get it i am new to it i am using spring tool suite for the project

Comment: Is there any way i can run this on my system as i just cannot get the error ;(

Comment: Where is your starter class?

Comment: Its there i have not added it to the question

Comment: Then add the code,  highly possible your controller isn't registered in spring boot context

Comment: Added it hope this is the class you are talking about , sorry if it isnt as i am new to it

Comment: OK I guess the problem is here only. You have not defined which packages to scan for annotations. Use @componentscan and add the right packages. Should work fine then.

Comment: But i have all the classes in the same package ans using@SpringBootApplication annotation scans all the classes in the package and aubpackages as told in the tutorial

Comment: Still no fix is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the below command, the project you have referred in github is working for me in my machine.

```
mvn clean package
```

or

`mvn clean install -U` (this will refresh all your dependencies and download them again)

and then run the application

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: When i tried running the command in the STS i am getting the following error in console updated in the question

Comment: Still no fix is they any other way

Comment: I think you're having an environment issue. Check whether JDK is installed in your machine. That's what the error you have posted is showing. If not, install JDK and run these commands again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539779/how-to-tell-if-jre-or-jdk-is-installed