# Build Failure error when Maven dependency for sql jdbc driver is added in pom.xml

Tags: java, database, eclipse, maven

I want to add the dependency for sql jdbc driver. Following is the snippet which I have added in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0.jre9-preview</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Then i right clicked the project and clicked on maven Install,Here i got a build failed error.It has downloaded the jar files but i am getting the below error.

```
Console output:

    - maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ hybridFramework ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [

INFO] Compiling 27 source files to C:\Automation Testing softwares\seleniumHybridFramework-master\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.761 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-29T17:20:22+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/45M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project hybridFramework: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Can Anyone Help me on This?..

Comment: Well, *Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?*
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539779/how-to-tell-if-jre-or-jdk-is-installed

Comment: The problem is not on the dependency, check at which JDK (if any) your build is referring: "No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?"

Comment: So,what should i do now

Comment: It depends on where you're doing this build: are you using an IDE with integrated maven capabilities?

Comment: @MatteoBaldi No i am using selenium webdriver

Comment: This is my JAVA_Home path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;

Comment: whether your are using java 8 or 9, also first check java version by - java  -version for JRE and for compiler check javac -version

Comment: @Afgan i am using Java 9.04

Comment: Then why this entry "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131;" in JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Have you overwrite compiler plugin in pom.xml ? Please add your pom.xml in question and one more thing are you building this on Eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not caused by the dependency but, as clearly staded in the build log:

> No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running
>   on a JRE rather than a JDK?

To set your JAVA_HOME and make Selenium WebDriver work look [here](https://www.utest.com/articles/how-to-configure-javajdk-for-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

I you are using eclipse IDE
Right click on project ->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Libraries

Configure JDK there instead of JRE

Comment: Can you tell me the steps how to configure JDK instead of JRE

Answer (score 0):

Maven is an external tool. Your IDE can call it with the right click and stuff but it is basically external tool. By default it uses your JAVA_HOME variable (which should point to JDK and not to JRE).  You can check for example with:

```
C:\Users\User>echo %JAVA_HOME%
 Output:   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152
```

You can also use

```
mvn -Dmaven.compiler.fork=true -Dmaven.compiler.executable=/path/to/the/javac compile
```

for compilation with a specific compiler but I guess that's not your problem. Just set your JAVA_HOME properly and you should be fine. Also you can try running command line maven. It will help debugging easier and is basically cleaner way to do it. Maybe the IDE is setting a java version different than the system one. You can check with

```
mvn -version
```

Also you can check if you have JDK or JRE by:

```
javac -version (this will work if you have JDK)
```

Comment: This is my JAVA_Home path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;  in environment variables

Comment: Try executing mvn -version from command line. It shows you maven version, java it is using, java version etc

Comment: Did you try mvn install from command line? Maybe the selenium ide is overriding the system settings?