# javac version and java version show different on command line

Tags: java, windows, javac

Before, I had java 8. I recently installed java 11. I moved my path `Java\jdk-11.0.7\bin` to the top of my environment variables. When I do `javac -version` it gives me version 11. But when I do `java -version`, it gives me version 8. How do I correct this? Specifically, I want to run a jar file that was compiled using java 11.

Comment: Is there a JAVA_HOME environment variable that still points to the JRE of Java 8?

Comment: No, it points to ```Java\jdk-11.0.7```

Comment: It doesn't matter what `JAVA_HOME` refers to, it only matters what's on the `PATH`. Apparently you have a JRE on the path before the JDK. To fix, put the JDK **first**, even before the windows folders.

Comment: In my ```PATH``` my JDK is at the very top already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you install JDK, it asks for the path of JRE as well. There is a possibility that you mentioned a different path for JRE than the `JAVA_HOME` or opted out the installation. If that happened, you should uninstall both, Java 8 and Java 11 and then install Java 11 again. However, before you do this, you can try/ensure the following things:

1. If you have put the `PATH` as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`, it won't work if the installation path (i.e. the path of `JAVA_HOME`) has space. In such a case, you need to put the absolute path instead of `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in the `PATH` environment variable.
2. Try the commands in a new cmd window.
3. Restart the system.
4. Move the path of JDK bin to the top in both, User variables as well as System variables.

Comment: Yes, I had to move System variables path up as well

Answer (score 2):

In linux distors you can configure java and javac with

```
update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: I think he asked for Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed JDK16 first, then install JDK1.8. After installing JDK1.8, I automatically updated it once from 1.8.2 to 1.8.3 and then turned off the update function.

First, go to the system environment variable
Move `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in PATH to the forefront

Then find two values in `PATH`:

- `C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Common Files \ Oracle \ Java \ JavaPath`
- `C: \ Program Files \ Common Files \ Oracle \ Java \ JavaPath`

One of the directory is also called java.exe file deletion or moves to elsewhere
Then `java -version` and `javac -version` will show version 16.0.2.

If we restore the java.exe  under "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Common Files \ Oracle \ Java \ JavaPath
Then there will be a case where the version number is inconsistent

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: More info on the `JavaPath` [here, I think it contains symlink files, or is a "junction" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51457823/1175496), more on [symlinks in Windows, here](https://superuser.com/q/524669/292784)