# Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I reinstalled my android studio since the sdk was not found and so on. After re installing java jdk and android studio , everything worked well until I got an error saying 'Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper' which I solved by changing the Gradle version. And now the error is 'Type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation.'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\loran\ASProjects\xylophone-flutter\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\loran.gradle\caches\6.8.2\scripts\4mawlyb2l5e9tefyvnpxva1kg).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you do a `./gradlew clean` and then open android studio and resync your gradle

Comment: @Sisir Where do I have to execute the command? In the IDE terminal didn't work for me.

Comment: The `gradlew` file is present inside your `android` folder. So open a cmd, navigate to `ProjectRoot\android` and then execute teh command

Comment: @Sisir `gradlew clean` and `gradlew` throws the same error `Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file`

Comment: setting java_home fixed error for me,
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio 4.1 Preview.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home

Comment: installed java 17 and it worked for me

Answer (score 34):

I also had this problem So I did install java 8
You might have Java 13 So install Java 8

Comment: This didn't work for me. Where do I have to select the java edition?

Comment: It worked for me, I had the jkd 16 installed, so I installed the jdk 8 and worked. The Google needs free itself from all that envolves the java. It's so boring setuping all. Tks man!

Comment: @vishal Do you mean JDK 16?

Comment: installing JAVA 11 worked for me because I was using Kotlin 1.8.0

Answer (score 25):

Java JDK 16 is the one that seems to lead to this issue try downgrading by downloading a lower version of JDK preferable JDK 8 or 11

To future individuals who will run to this error. Here is the link to download the JDK  enjoy your coding experience don't forget to change the path too.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Comment: @Sana'aAl-ahdal I am glad it did Enjoy your coding buddy.

Comment: thanks bro, life saver, and I want to point out that this website: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/" shows a way to deal with JAVA_HOME if you needed.

Comment: installing JAVA 11 worked for me because I was using Kotlin 1.8.0

Answer (score 11):

You can try this, It works for me.

Open the Android module to a new window and automatically download all necessary libraries after successfully building finished run the app.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked 100% for me. You are a true savior.

Answer (score 11):

So the problem arises from inconsistency in the Java version installed on your machine, the default Java version configured on your android studio and the gradle version for your project.
So building upon the answer given by Tafita Raza I fixed it following the steps below

- Check your java version and remember it, use "java -version" in terminal
- Go to your android studio path installation
- In newer versions of android studio go to Andriod Studio/jbe while in older versions go to Android Studio/jre/ and edit the file named "release"
- Replace the value of JAVA_VERSION with the version of Java installed on your machine if it's not the same as the java version on your computer
- Now go into the project folder you are building and check if the [Gradle version is compatible with the Java you have installed](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) (latest table below, as of 2023-11-12)

| Java version | Support for compiling/testing/… | Support for running Gradle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | N/A | 2.0 |
| 9 | N/A | 4.3 |
| 10 | N/A | 4.7 |
| 11 | N/A | 5.0 |
| 12 | N/A | 5.4 |
| 13 | N/A | 6.0 |
| 14 | N/A | 6.3 |
| 15 | 6.7 | 6.7 |
| 16 | 7.0 | 7.0 |
| 17 | 7.3 | 7.3 |
| 18 | 7.5 | 7.5 |
| 19 | 7.6 | 7.6 |
| 20 | 8.1 | 8.3 |
| 21 | 8.4 | N/A |

- I had java 19.0.2 installed on my system so according to the table I need gradle version 7.6 to build a project. You can also check the official  website gradle if your java version is not listed https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html
- Go into your project_name/android/gradle/wrapper and edit the file gradle-wrapper.properties
- Replace the distributionUrl with the version of gradle compatible with the java version on your system
  [image: DistributionUrl Example]

Comment: Thank you! The compatibility table you provided was very useful. I had Java 17.0.6 and gradle 4.0.2. I updated gradle to 7.3.0 in my flutter project and now the app runs without problems.

Comment: What if I don't have java installed on my PC?   both bash and CMD say "no java."

Comment: @PeteAlvin Go to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk21-windows to download the Java program that is compatible with your machine (I guess it is Windows)

Answer (score 9):

**FOUND IT !**
No need to change your JDK version, follow the steps to resolve the issue:

- check your java version and remember it, use "java -version" in terminal
- go to your android studio path installation
- then in: Android Studio/jre/ open the file named "release"
- take attention of the value of JAVA_VERSION field
- if it's not the same as the java version on your computer, just change it with the version installed on your computer.

That's it, i hope it will resolve your issue like it resolves mine.

Try it and give a feedback.

Comment: I don't have a folder called jre

Comment: You can add a folder jre, and then copy the contents from jbr into the jre folder.  Then reload your terminal before checking anything, like flutter doctor.

Comment: Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: bash: java: command not found

Comment: These instructions are not clear; I have an empty jre directory but I do have jbr directory

Comment: This answer provides useful troubleshooting information, but isn't a complete resolution to fix the issue. The phrasing in the answer could be improved (and I would edit, but "edit queue is too full")

Answer (score 6):

Try installing the latest Gradle package gradle-7.1.1, if you are using Java JDK 16 installed. To do this open android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file and under distribution url, update the gradle version to 7.1.1 (or the latest). After that, inside your Flutter project directory, run the following command in the terminal:

```
cd android && ./gradlew
```

Comment: gradle-7.4 for JDK 17

Answer (score 6):

I removed the JAVA_HOME path to the JAVA download and changed JAVA_HOME path to the following:

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

I am now coding

Comment: worked for me (or at least, moved me on to the next error :-p )

Comment: Just installed Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 today. This worked for me, BUT, I had to use: \Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr   (note: jbr instead of jre).

Comment: This seemed to be the problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: send your address, need to send some cookies and special thanks to @user1544428

Answer (score 5):

mainly you have jdk16 i tried to install java 8 and set env to java 8 it worked for me

Comment: installing JAVA 11 worked for me because I was using Kotlin 1.8.0

Answer (score 2):

In gradle wrapper.properties,
change the code to this -

```
distribution Url = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

In build.gradle,
change the code to this -

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3"
```

And then, hit flutter run in terminal

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with React Native and I solved following the next steps:

1. Open Android Studio
2. File -> Open your project (select the android
   folder)
3. Wait for the gradlew finish the build process
4. Then Menu Build -> Rebuild project
5. Now you can compile `npx react-native run-android`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this!
Remove `package android` from the top of settings.gradle. This helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to your Android Studio path -> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
open jbr folder -> copy all files -> then go back -> paste all the files in the jre folder and "replace the files in the destination".
It works for me in two different laptops. I have latest jdk version - 19.0.2

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is change the java version to 11 and provide JAVA_HOME to jdk 11. You need to ensure to delete any other java versions (latest). Then restart the system and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The full and final super-easy & latest solution of this problem is to create an environment variable with -

Variable - JAVA_HOME
Value - C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Enter Android Studio > Contents
2. Copy jbr folder
3. Paste and rename jre
4. flutter clean
5. flutter run
6. chill

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs, this might because you have installed the latest JDK such as JDK 16. You download and install JDK 8 and uninstall JDK 16. Then restart the desktop/laptop and try launch and run flutter run again. It should be working fine.

Comment: installing JAVA 11 worked for me because I was using Kotlin 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on Windows 10, my JAVA_HOME was set to `JAVA SE 16 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16` and when I looked at the `release file in java jre in android studio, C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\release, I found that the the JAVA_VERSION WAS "11.0.10" (java 11) for short`. So I `changed the java installation on my PC to Java 11`, update *JAVA_HOME* in my environment variables to point to the new java (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12) and `restarted android studio`, Then everything worked.

You can get your java 11 from here.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html. Change 11 to 8, 16 etc to get the download link for the java version you need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with having Java 13 or 16 installed on your computer. The current version of Flutter does not work with Java 13 and 16. Just uninstall either of these that you may have installed and installed Java 8 or Java 11. Restart your computer to effect the update. Everything should be fine afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using flutter. I fixed it ensuring the `android-studio-dir` path was set correctly.
You set it up using `flutter config --android-studio-dir="android studio path"`.
Then run flutter doctor and ensure flutter can see Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In 'adnroid/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties'
Change distributionUrl to version 7.0.1

In 'android/build.gradle'
Change 'com.android.tools.build:gradle' to version 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Java 11 is the only supported version by Flutter as for now. It compiles and installs.
Previously I had this error using Java 19 and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

You might want update your gradle version.
Check the supported gradle <-> kotlin <-> java version on their page.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing is related to the flutter build process and it occurs when a required input or output annotation is missing from the assets property of the FlutterTask.

```
task buildFlutter(type: FlutterTask) {
// Add the @Input annotation to the assets property
@Input List<String> assets = ["assets/images/", "assets/fonts/"]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Please make sure your jdk is compatible with your android studio/adroid sdk. In my case jdk 19 was not supported with android studio electric eel so i had to install jdk 17.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a project.
Just opening it with the Android Studio, and then running the command, seemed to resolve it for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this using

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java8-amd64/bin/java
```

In my recents projects, I use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

for example, I created alias to change between

```
alias changeJavaTo1.8='sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java8-amd64/bin/java'
alias changeJavaTo17='sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'
```

Answer (score 0):

change distribution url in gradle-wrapper.properties to latest distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

and module build.gradle
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try to disable AVAST, check system vatiables path for JDK and SDK, clear cache with yarn.

Comment: When providing support it's always better to provide more detailed instructions + AVAST is unlikely to have an issue as it's not been specified to be used by the stackoverflower

Comment: In my case i have to disable avast

Comment: Fair enough, at least you tried helping.

Answer (score -2):

Change the `JAVA_HOME` to your Android Studio root such as:
`D:\Android\Android Studio\jbr` (not jre).

I don't change the java version, just changed the `JAVA_HOME`, it solved this question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I also had this problem So I just upgrade my flutter by the command `flutter upgrade` .

or You can Clean the Gradle cache: Similar to the previous error, you can try deleting the Gradle cache to resolve the issue. Navigate to the directory mentioned in the error message (C:\Users\loran.gradle\caches\6.8.2) and delete the scripts folder. Then, try rebuilding your project to see if the error is resolved.

Comment: Most or all of your eight answers from the last three days appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  This appears to be GPT that you've (poorly) edited.  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.