# android studio Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file `C:\Users\moazm\StudioProjects\untitled\android\settings.gradle`
  `C:\Users\moazm\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe`.

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 605ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

when i tried to run my app on my phone or any emulator it didn't work because of this error ....
can you help me with this error , i tried so many solutions but the error stay the same and i also delete android studio and install it again and the error still the same

EDIT:::::::
i update the sdkversion on build->app->build.gradle
compileSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 31

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with the newer JDK versions. Try using JDK 8 or 11. I have had this issue before, but this thread helped me to solve it,

[Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240279/could-not-open-settings-generic-class-cache-for-settings-file)