# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception in settings.gradle

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\lev2d\StudioProjects\fire_service\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\lev2d.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Comment: Do a "flutter clean".

Then run again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240279/could-not-open-settings-generic-class-cache-for-settings-file)