# How to run flutter app on android mobile from VS Code on Linux?

Tags: android, linux, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I have configured flutter on my Linux Mint and I have downloaded the android command line tools instead of Android Studio. I have also updated the gradle and commandline-tools path on my Linux Mint. Now I want to install the app on my android smartphone and test. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Run **`Flutter doctor -v`** to check for any issues (You may have to accept android-licences with **`flutter doctor --android-licenses`**).
2. Connect your android device (Debugging mode should be enabled in the developer options) with USB
3. You can see connected device in VSCode at bottom-right corner,select your device
4. Press F5 to run or use "**`Flutter run`**" command

Comment: Thanks but already did all that.

Answer (score 1):

You can type this in your terminal in your project directory to get the release apk for your project

```
 flutter build apk --release
```

The release apk file will be in build>app>outputs>flutter-apk>app-release.apk

If you want to debug the app, then you can connect your android phone to your pc and then run this command in the terminal:

```
flutter run
```

and then select your android device from the options to debug your app

Comment: It generated error with something like `Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file ....`

Comment: `
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/home/dhiraj/Documents/FlutterProjects/firstapp/android/settings.gradle'
(/home/dhiraj/gradle/bin/caches/7.0.2/scripts/bt53u1oym6apy0m101vnrgrbi).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                    2,954ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
`

Comment: What java version are you using?

Comment: java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240279/could-not-open-settings-generic-class-cache-for-settings-file