# Why is the app not running in android simulator?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I am writing an app in flutter, it runs in my ios simulator but it doesn't run on the android simulator. When starting it on android simulator the flutter logo just pops up and disappears, the debug process continues running endlessly without closing or throwing any errors. What could be the issue?

Expecting the Android simulator to run the app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there any log in debug console?

Comment: @yaldamohasseli only this:
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.

And it could go on for hours.

Comment: does it happen for all of your flutter projects?

Comment: Yes, but not on ios simulator. @yaldamohasseli

Comment: Did u see the first answer here?  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018919/not-able-to-launch-flutter-app-on-android-device