# i started work on my final year project on react native i face one error when i run this command "npm run android " then it show error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

```
npm run andriod
```

**Error**
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Sharjil\AwesomeProject\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Sharjil.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\9hquuo8ig26y11gv08ef208wj).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240279/could-not-open-settings-generic-class-cache-for-settings-file)

Comment: your java version seems to be incompatible with your java version. Check both versions and upgrade/downgrade either to get a compatible combination