# exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

I had finished dart course and starting a Flutter course i downlouded android studio and the flutter app worked very will on chrom , but when i run it on the virtual device of th emulator it does not work , I have done almost evry sloution(about Java && Gradle) but nothing worke and this is the error :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\hp\StudioProjects\flutter_1\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\ea4ydi90mwjg9g63m7r6nimmx).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

gradle version : Gradle 8.0.2
java version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17

I think the error because java && gradle version

Comment: Have you tried running the build itself with Java 17?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240279/could-not-open-settings-generic-class-cache-for-settings-file)